# Como passar array php para javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Estou com problema para passar o array $json[] para a o Javascript, será que alguém poderia me ajudar.

```html
<?php
    include_once ('../conf/conexaoBanco.php');
    $mensagem = "";

    $stmt=$conectarBanco->prepare("SELECT * FROM orcamento");
   $stmt->execute();
   **$json = [];
   while ($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       extract($row);
       $json[] = (int)$quantidade;
   }**
```

?>

```
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h2 class="sub-orcamento">Orçamento Mensal</h2>

                    <canvas class="line-chart"></canvas>

                    <!-- Chartjs -->

                    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

                    <script>
                        var ctx = document.getElementsByClassName("line-chart");

                        //Type, Data e options
                        var chartGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                            type: 'line',
                            data: {
                                labels: ["Jan","Fev","Mar","Abr","Mai","Jun","Jul","Ago","Set","Out","Nov","Dez"],
                            datasets: [{
                                label:"Orçados de <?php echo date('Y') ?>",
                                **data: {"<?php $quantidade ?>"},**
                                borderWidth: 6,
                                borderColor: 'rgba(77,166,253,0.8)'
                            }]

                            }
                        })    

                    </script>
```

Comment: E por que precisa passar um array do PHP para o JSON? Conhece os conceitos de Client-Side e Server-Side? Poderia [edit] sua pergunta e elaborar um [mcve]?

Comment: Anderson Carlos Woss preciso passar esse array para o Javascript para poder gerar um gráfico do Chartsjs com base nas informações do meu banco de dados. Sim conheço o conceito Client-Side e Server-Side, mais caso tenha alguma sugestão melhor fica a vontade para me informar pois estou aqui para aprender

Comment: Bruno, vc diz estar com problema para passar um array PHP para o JS, mas não explicou qual é o problema. Vc apenas disse que está com problema e colocou um código. Isso não ajuda muito em conseguir uma solução, pois não se sabe qual é o problema ou o objetivo disso.

Comment: Sam o problema que estou tendo é que não sei como passar o array $json[] para o atributo data do Chatsjs e já tentei de varias formas buscando pela internet só que nenhuma me da uma solução que eu consiga compriender como fazer esse procedimento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui tem um exemplo com base no conteúdo que você informou:

```html
<?php
$quantidade = [10, 15, 8, 5, 6, 9, 10, 7, 8, 11, 4, 5];
?>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
  <h2 class="sub-orcamento">Orçamento Mensal</h2>

  <canvas class="line-chart"></canvas>

  <!-- Chartjs -->

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

  <script>
   var ctx = document.getElementsByClassName("line-chart");

   //Type, Data e options
   var chartGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
     labels: ["Jan","Fev","Mar","Abr","Mai","Jun","Jul","Ago","Set","Out","Nov","Dez"],
    datasets: [{
     label:"Orçados de <?php echo date('Y') ?>",
     data: <?php echo json_encode($quantidade) ?>,
     borderWidth: 6,
     borderColor: 'rgba(77,166,253,0.8)'
    }]

    }
   })    

  </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Enviar o Json do Php para o Javascript pode facilitar as coisas, em especial quando trabalhamos com arquivos em base64 usando JsonURL, já que as funções do PHP não tem suporte para isso e as strings precisam ser normalizadas (https://base64.guru/developers/php/examples/base64url).
Para facilitar, uma das soluções pode ser converter da seguinte forma:

```
$arrayJson = array(
  "nome"  => "joao",
  "idade" => 35
);

//codificar para Json (isso será passado para o Javascript)
$json = json_encode($arrayJson);
```

No Javascript você vai receber este valor normalmente (passando uma variável do Php para Js):

```
  <script>
  var jsonJS = <?=$json?>;
  //isso é um objeto json, então para acessar os valores trate ele como objeto:
  alert('nome: ' + jsonJS.nome);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a função [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) para converter um valor PHP em uma representação JSON.

> Pode ser qualquer valor PHP, exceto [resource](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.resource.php).

```
$json = [];
while ($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    extract($row);
    $json[] = (int) $quantidade;
}

$json = json_encode($json);
```

Em seu código javascript, basta printar a variável `$json` que já está em formato JSON.

```
data: <?php echo $json ?>,
```

Answer (score -2):

Transform array and JSON using json_encode. In javascript get this JSON

```
const MyArrayJS = JSON.parse('<?= json_encode($myArrayPHP); ?>');
```